# Faststone Image Resizer equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I am moving over to Ubuntu from Windows (gradually) and have used Faststone Image Resizer for Windows for a while and found it very good.

Is there an equivalent piece of software for Ubuntu that someone can recommend to me?

Comment: What features did it have that you are looking for in alternative software?  People that just know what linux software or webservice software does, might not be familiar with that one killer feature that made this a solution for you.

Comment: @hbdgaf just need to resize images without losing any quality and simple to use.

Comment: scaling up or down.  one is simple resize, the other is rasterizing to scale up like http://rasterbator.net/

Comment: sorry scale down, for web.

Comment: Gimp can do that and can be driven from the cli - see the "Changing the Size (Dimensions) of an Image (Scale)" in [this](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMP_Quickies/)

Comment: ok thanks @hbdgaf, I have GIMP installed and need to get familiar with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/), it works for my needs.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to compare two images in a single directory. Any idea what to do when I want to compare two images in two different directories?