# Compare different directory images side by side using XnView MP

Tags: image-viewers, diff, xnview

I am trying to compare two images side by side. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/577283/775359) suggested [XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/). It works great when I want to compare two images in a single directory. I select the two images in the browser and then `Tools > Compare`.

However, if my images are in two different directories, I first have to copy them to a single folder, then go to that folder in the XnView browser, select the two images and then compare. Is there a way to directly compare two images in two different directories?

PS: I am open to using different image viewer for this purpose.

Update:
I found a slightly better way by marking the respective images under a specific category under the browser and then go to `Categories Filter` to select the images and compare. Even then, I would prefer open two images in two different tabs from the file explorer and click compare.

Comment: You would have to make a [feature request](https://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewforum.php?f=60&sid=a38cd57fb6c538d7652742537a5d5212) with the developers of the software. I think it's not possible without modifying the source code and recompile. Since the end user license clearly states `You may not modify, reverse engineer, decompile, disassemble the SOFTWARE except to the extent you may be expressly permitted by copyright holders` we can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, [it already exists](https://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=42917&p=184617#p184617). Hope the developers pick it up

Comment: make a soft link to one of them to be in the same directory as the other. a hassle though.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually thinking of writing a short script where I'll specify the two images and it will copy them to a temporary directory where I can use XnView to compare. But sym-link seems like a better option.